# What is the purpose of replaceAll() method of List interface?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, replaceall

If we declare an object with Collection reference type and call replacAll() on this object-
`Collection al = new ArrayList<>();`
`al.replaceAll(param);`
We cannot call this method because its not present in Collection interface
Now if we declare an Object with List reference type
`List al = new ArrayList<>();`
`al.replaceAll(param);`
We can call this method because its present in List interface but it will execute ArrayList implementation and not List implementation because the object is of ArrayList type.

Now my question is what is the purpose of List implementation for this method

Comment: I believe this question is about `default` keyword in general, not just about `replaceAll`. If so, there's a similar question: [What is the purpose of the default keyword in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578427/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-default-keyword-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

`ArrayList` is not the only type of list. There are other implementers of the `List` interface. You can even write your own `List` implementation.

You are right in that `ArrayList` has its own implementation of `replaceAll`, hence overriding the default implementation of `replaceAll` in `List`. `ArrayList` does this possibly because it could offer a "better" implementation than the default one in `List`.

However, if you use a `LinkedList`, for example, then the default implementation of `replaceAll`, as written in `List`, will be executed. `LinkedList` doesn't provide its own implementation of `replaceAll`. This is the point of `replaceAll`'s implementation in `List` - to provide a default implementation, so that *not every implementation has to implement* `replaceAll`, but if they do, that's fine as well.

Comment: …especially the 3rd party list implementations that existed before Java 8 and hence, can not override a method introduced in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

In both examples it's the only one implementation - ArrayList. Collection and List are interfaces, not implementations.

Comment: `List` interface have a default `replaceAll` method implementation.

Comment: Yeah. I misunderstood the essence of the question. The interfaces default methods context of the question is unclear here.