# Will making an existing method default in a Java interface breaks binary compaibility

Tags: java

I have an existing interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
    void methodA();
    void methodB();
}
```

I made methodB default and added a default implementation:

```
interface MyInterface {
    void methodA;
    default void methodB() {
    }
}
```

Suddently, some of the system that uses MyInterface starts to show ClassNotFoundException when they start use the new version of MyInterface.

I am worrying if my change could potentially break backward compatibility. Can someone please advise

Comment: Are you running this on a JVM that is from before the era of default interface methods?

Comment: The change to a default method probably didn't cause a ClassNotFoundException, there were likely problems there already.  A change to default method can cause an IncompatibleClassChangeError as has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578427/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-default-keyword-in-java)